# How to use variable initiated in SQL query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I made a query to get Max value of a certain column

```
sSQLmax = "SELECT MAX([tablename]!rowname) as MaxNum FROM [tablename]"
```

I want to use MaxNum value. I tried it in a Msgbox and gave me a blank value. I tried all these:

```
MsgBox "MaxNum" & MaxNum

MsgBox "MaxNum" & sSQLMAX.MaxNum

MsgBox "MaxNum" & sSQLMAX!MaxNum
```

More of the code

```
Dim db As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(sSQLmax)
```

but none works, Im sure its simple but it escapes me

Comment: lol, you can't do it like this ;) How are you executing the query and where are you storing the results?

Comment: We need to know some more information around how your returning your results from the database. Are you using ADO / DAO for example?

Comment: just edited in the rest of the code, So DAO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code you are only setting a variable to a string.  You are not actually doing anything with it.  This is probably more of what you are looking for:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset, sSQLmax As String
sSQLmax = "SELECT MAX([tablename].rowname) as MaxNum FROM [tablename]"
Set db = CurrentDb

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(sSQLmax, dbOpenDynaset)

If (rst.RecordCount <> 0) Then
  rst.MoveFirst
  MsgBox "MaxNumber: " & rst.Fields("rowname")
End If
```

Comment: thanks for clearing that up, I moved my msgbox after setting rst but it only worked with "!"  MsgBox "Maxnum " & rst!MaxNum

Answer (score 0):

Try the DMax function

```
Dim result as String
result = DMax("[COLUMN NAME]", "[TABLE NAME]")
```